# Changing the subject of selected items found in a search

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to change the subject of e-mails that match a search criteria.

For example, a user searches for 'apples' and then uses this macro to change all the e-mails found to have **[APPLES]** in the subject.

The code I have changes the subject of a single e-mail that the user has clicked on, and not all the selected e-mails. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `ActiveExplorer` and Selection functions.

```vb
Sub AddString()
    Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim aItem As Object
    
    Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Dim iItemsUpdated As Integer
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strString As String
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Object
    
    ' User input
    strString = InputBox("Enter the project code")
    iItemsUpdated = 0
    
    ' Empty value or cancel button
    If strString = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Writes string to e-mail subject
    Set myOlExp = myolApp.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
    For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
        strTemp = "[" & strString & "] " & myOlSel.Item(x).Subject
        myOlSel.Item(x).Subject = strTemp
        myOlSel.Item(x).Save
        iItemsUpdated = iItemsUpdated + 1
    Next x
    
    ' Tells user how many items have been updated
    MsgBox iItemsUpdated & " of " & mail.Items.Count & " Messages Updated"
    Set myolApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `myOlExp.SelectAllItems` to your code, like

```
' Writes string to e-mail subject
Set myOlExp = myolApp.ActiveExplorer
myOlExp.SelectAllItems
Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
```